# Partitioning a SanDisk Cruzer Extreme 64GB drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I want to partition my Cruzer Extreme into a 32 Gb YUMI bootable recovery/install drive FAT32 and a 32 Gb exFAT data partition but Windows disk manager is not even letting me delete the volume and with GParted if I create two partitions one of them is not accessible from Windows.
Any other USB drive is partitioning fine, though!

[image]

After doing the partitions with Gparted in Lubuntu, where they work fine and can write in them, this is what happens:
[image]
A summary of the warning message would be that there was an unexpected error, check the event viewer, restart the disk manager or reboot. Not very helpful. :(

So, is there a special way to partition this USB the way I want or is it just that this USB's controller doesn't allow for that? Are all Sandisk sticks suffering from this issue?

Comment: "check the event viewer" - so did you check [what information appears in the event logs?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) Any errors?

Comment: All these are perfectly normal. It's simply the way Windows treats SCSI drives with Removable Medium Bit set to 1 (`Extraíble`), which is a typical case for USB flash drives.

Comment: @DavidPostill No errors whatsoever! :(

Comment: @TomYan But other USB flash drives can be partitioned fine. :S

Comment: @Deses You just happen to have many other drives have RMB set to 0, which will be shown as `Basic` instead of `Removable` in `Disk Management`. (No idea how `Basic` is called in Spanish, but you should see a word other than `Extraíble` for those drives that you claim to be "partitionable")

Comment: @TomYan That's spot on. I never noticed that difference in `Disk management`. Would like to add that as an answer so I can mark it as solved? (Also, `Basic` in Spanish is `Básico`. The more you know!)